# SQL multiple condition

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, netbeans

I have a table that saves purchase date and customer name that would be something like this:

```
|Name   | Item | Purchase Date |
|Sam    |Soap  | 03-09-2018    |
|Edwin  |Coffee| 28-08-2018    |
|Gary   |Tea   | 24-09-2018    |
|Sam    |Milk  | 09-10-2018    |
|Tiffany|Sugar | 17-10-2018    |
|Sam    |Cocoa | 30-10-2018    |
```

example, i want to get the output like this:

```
|Sam    |Milk  | 09-10-2018    |
|Sam    |Cocoa | 30-10-2018    |
```

so the code should be like this:

```
"Select * from purchase_table where customer_name =
'"+customer_name_text+"' AND purchase_date BETWEEN 
'"+from_date.getDate()+"' AND 
'"+until_date.getDate()+"' ";
```

where customer_name_text is the input from user to find a specific customer name, from_date is also the input from user to make a range date between until_date jDateChooser, the date is between 1st October 2018 until 31th Oct 2018

but instead output like above, the output seems wrong, it would be something like this :

```
|Sam    |Soap  | 03-09-2018    |
|Sam    |Milk  | 09-10-2018    |
|Sam    |Cocoa | 30-10-2018    |
```

any suggestion will be accepted

Comment: Verify whether the `from_date` has been set correctly from your jDateChooser? If so, also please run the query using prepared statements, like `select * from purchase_table where customer_name = ? AND purchase_date BETWEEN ? AND ?`. Using string concatenation is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the date format like this '2012-10-01 00:00:00' (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS)
see sample below,

```
"Select * from purchase_table where customer_name =
'sam' AND purchase_date BETWEEN 
'2012-10-01 00:00:00' AND 
'2012-10-31 00:00:00' ";
```

Comment: will try it later because i already saved the format date in "dd-MM-yyyy" format, i think i need a new database saved in format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS' like you said before

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM purchase_table WHERE customer_name = '"+customer_name_text
+"' AND purchase_date >= '"+from_date.getDate()
+"' AND purchase_date <= '"+until_date.getDate()+"' ";
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, tried your code and still having same issue

Answer (score 0):

yes i'm suggest, too, give a format to the date. For example:
to_date('03 Dec 2018','DD Mon YYYY HH24:mi:ss')

Select * from purchase_table 
where customer_name = 'Sam' 
and purchase_date between to_date('01 Oct 2018','DD Mon YYYY HH24:mi:ss') and to_date('31 Oct 2018','DD Mon YYYY HH24:mi:ss');

Comment: will try it later because i already saved the format date in "dd-MM-yyyy" format, i think i need a new database saved in format 'DD Mon YYYY HH24:mi:ss' like you said before

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to check your default date format in SQL Database
the deafult format of sql is :

DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD.
DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.
SMALLDATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.
TIMESTAMP - format: a unique number.

you can also change the date format or pass the date in default date format

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the date format like this '2012-10-01 00:00:00' (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS)

see sample below,

Because, SQL only accepts date format like this: (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS)

1) Accept the date from a user then write a function to structure date like above format using `getDate()` function that's it.

`"Select * from purchase_table where customer_name =
'sam' AND purchase_date BETWEEN 
'2012-10-01 00:00:00' AND 
'2012-10-31 00:00:00' ";`

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL query to fetch data within a date range:

```
" SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        `purchase_table`
    WHERE
        customer_name = '"+customer_name_text+"'
        AND
        (
            purchase_date >= '"+from_date.getDate()+"'
            AND
            purchase_date <= '"+until_date.getDate()+"'
        )
";
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, still doesn't work using your code. maybe there's an error outside of the query probably will check that later

Comment: @Jokurilisme,  is dynamic values from variables [ customer_name_text,  from_date.getDate(),  until_date.getDate() ] placed properly in query? check sql query for that values, if all values placed properly then SQL query will be work properly.... for testing you can check query with fixed values to make sure that query returning correct result or not.